# Update android contact by Expo project

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, expo

I have project a use Expo Contact module to update automatically  contact .
This is my script to update phone number selected

```
const updateContact = async (callId, newCall) => {
  getSingleContact(callId)
    .then(resp => {
        .......
        Contacts.updateContactAsync(contact)
            .then(updCall => console.log('updateCall :::> ', updCall))
    })
    .catch(error => console.log('Error detected :::> ', error))
 }
```

My program return callId

Please explian me how to update data by Contact module

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve this problem by react-native-contacts.
Because for default Expo has not assure this function [click for more information](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/contacts/).

This is Expo docx (Contacts.updateContactAsync(contact))

> On Android, you can use presentFormAsync to make edits to contacts. Due to an iOS bug, nonGregorianBirthday cannot be modified.

```
Contacts.updateContactAsync(contact: Contact): Promise<string>
```

For [react-native-contacts](https://github.com/morenoh149/react-native-contacts) Module

1. Install

   yarn add react-native-contacts
2. Permissions

> Add READ_CONTACTS and/or WRITE_PROFILE permissions to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

3. Exemple

   click [here](https://github.com/morenoh149/react-native-contacts)